# Readjusting columns after pandas concatenation

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe as follows which I generate after `Pandas concat` operation:

```
Date      Col1  Col2    Col1    Col2
1/1/2021    1   3       
2/1/2021    2   4       
3/1/2021                5        6
4/1/2021                7        8
```

I want to get the following:

```
Date      Col1  Col2    
1/1/2021    1   3       
2/1/2021    2   4       
3/1/2021    5   6
4/1/2021    7   8
```

I am not sure how to achieve the above.

Edit: The code is grandfathered so I can't concatenate based on axis=0. Essentially this is a post concat question

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to remove the `NaN` values

```
df.set_index('Date').stack().unstack()
```

Another approach would be to use `groupby` + `first` along the columns axis

```
df.set_index('Date').groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
```

---

```
          Col1  Col2
Date                
1/1/2021   1.0   3.0
2/1/2021   2.0   4.0
3/1/2021   5.0   6.0
4/1/2021   7.0   8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this when doing the concatenation: `pd.concat(....,axis=0)`. You will not need to readjust after the concat operation.

Update: You still can do this post-concatenation. Split the dataframe into two, based on the condition col1/col2 is equal to null. Then do the concat with `axis=0`.